# Error when unable to return a certain value in a record view form in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to make the select field in a record view field not show the patient's blood type, I am using CodeIniter 4 and the patient's blood type is not being returned to me.

- `view.php`

```
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="blood_type_id">Blood type:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="blood_type_id" disabled>
                <option <?= (old('blood_type_id') === null || old('blood_type_id') == '') ? 'selected' : '' ?> value=""><?= 'Choose the blood type' ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($blood_types as $id => $ts): ?>
                    <option <?= (string) old('blood_type_id') === $id ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="<?= $id + 1?>"><?= $ts['description'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php echo session()->getFlashdata('errors')["blood_type_id"] ?? ""; ?>
        </div>
```

- `PacientController.php`

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $model = new PacientModel();
        $blood = new BloodTypeModel();
        $data = [
            'pacients' => $model->getPacient($id),
            'blood_types' => $blood->findAll(), 
        ];
        return view('pacient/edit', $data);
    }
```

Comment: You are unable to not show the blood type?

Comment: Is that `view.php` the one used in your controller in `view('pacient/edit'...)`? Also remember that `disabled` elements don't get submitted

Comment: @brombeer just have set the value of register.